# Recorrer resultados devueltos de un procedimiento almacenado en PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado en SQL Server que devuelve una lista de datos.
Quiero leer esos datos en php pero me salen errores o no arroja datos. agradezco cualquier ayuda.

```
$myparams['FECHA_INICIAL'] = "20220101 00:00:00";
$myparams['FECHA_FINAL'] = "20220331 23:59:59";
$myparams['COD_INFORME'] = "I21";
$myparams['COD_SUBINFORME'] = "I21-C2";

$procedure_params = array(
      array(&$myparams['FECHA_INICIAL'], SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
      array(&$myparams['FECHA_FINAL'], SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
      array(&$myparams['COD_INFORME'], SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
      array(&$myparams['COD_SUBINFORME'], SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
);

$sql = "EXEC INFORMES_WEB @FECHA_INICIAL=?,@FECHA_FINAL=?,@COD_INFORME=?,@COD_SUBINFORME=?";
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($con_ssql, $sql, $procedure_params);
if(sqlsrv_execute($stmt)){
    while($res = sqlsrv_next_result($stmt)){
        echo $res[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: [Fijate esto](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/connect/php/how-to-retrieve-output-parameters-using-the-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-ver16) si te sirve.

Answer (score -1):

Intenta de la siguiente manera:

```php
 $sql = "call INFORMES_WEB()";
            $arreglo = array();
            if ($consulta = $this->conexion->conexion->query($sql)) {
                while ($consulta_VU = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta)) {
                    
                        $arreglo["data"][] = $consulta_VU;
                    
                }
                return $arreglo;
                $this->conexion->cerrar();
            }
```

Lo que esto hará es recorrer a la consulta devuelta (tabla) y agruparla en una suerte de arrays; esto hará que puedas almacenarlos en PHP de manera más sencilla.

> La parte en la que se ve:
>
> ```php
> $this->conexion->conexion
> ```
>
> Es como yo suelo hacer el llamado al método de conexión; esto claramente variará según cómo tu conectes y llames a tu BD.

Comment: Gracias por laidea, pero no puedo usar CALL porque la consulta es sobre SQL Server.